# ''ls' is not recognized as an internal' in python

Tags: python

While working on a python tutorial, i have following code that doesn't run and I dont recognize. what kind of import should I do for them in order to have it run?

I did import os, import sys, not helping.

```
!sudo chown -R jupyter:jupyter /home/jupyter/training-data-analyst
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


!ls -l ../data/*.csv
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

!head ../data/taxi*.csv
'head' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I am using Jupiter notebook

Comment: Windows doesn't have an `ls` command... Also, you skipped your first error when creating the question?

Comment: Those are unix/linux shell commands and you're clearly on Windows. You'll need some kind of linux-like shell. Although this site doesn't allow recommendation questions, I'll say that your options include Ubuntu for Windows 10, Git Bash, and MinGW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Python code. These are Unix commands, not meant to be ran in Windows, which appears that you are.

You shouldn't need to modify permissions of example data, and Python has native functions for listing contents of directory and files that you should be using instead.

For example, `os.glob()` and `open()`

---

Based on the usage of `/home/jupyter`, I would *guess* you skipped part of the tutorial that is using a Docker container

Comment: I took the whole thing from a web served notebook and tried to run on my local computer. Guess it not gonna work

Comment: It would, but you're at least going to need Docker or run Jupyter from WSL2

Comment: Personally, I suggest reading the Python code after those cells because the only purpose of those other commands is to show you that the data exists

Comment: You mean like a virtual environment like Ubuntu mentioned above. Its too much for a starter. I only need read in couple of csvs for learning data science

Comment: there are nothing above, they are on the beginning except for bunch imports in the middle

Comment: Well, I cannot see your notebook. My point was that 1) You aren't expected to download that notebook exactly and run it as-is unless you have the exact same file paths 2) Since it isn't Python code, then there isn't much point in running those cells anyway